# <function TextIOWrapper.close> comes up when trying to write HTML page

Tags: python, html

Ok so I'm creating a HTML website using python (and more specifically Jupyter) for uni on sports team and stats and I'm getting an error when writing pages.
My main page worked fine:

```
openfile1 = open("mainpage.html", "w")
openfile1.write(header + body.format(header="...",
                                para="....",
                                table="",
                                link="...",
                                linkn="..."))
openfile1.close()
```

I replaced the string with ... for the question,

but when i tried to write a seconds page:

```
openfile2 = open("results.html", "w")
openfile2.write(header + body.format(header="...",
                                para="....",
                                table="",
                                link="...",
                                linkn="..."))
openfile2.close
```

and its giving me an output:

```
<function TextIOWrapper.close>
```

and not writing anything into the file created in my jupyter folder
i would think it was the functions I was using but as the first page works perfectly I cant understand why the proceeding pages won't output

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Compare: `.close()`, `.close`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
openfile2.close
```

You are not calling the function close you need to add parenthesis () to call a function. Change the line to

```
openfile2.close()
```